# How to remove : from the time stamp in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I have time like this `14:21:49`

Now I need to remove the `:` from the timestamp which means output should become like this `142149`

```
Input:
  scan_utc_input_time="14:21:49"
Output:
  scan_utc_output_time="142149
```

Comment: There are several places where timestamps occur in `bash`. From the output of which command do you want to remove the `:`?

Comment: Pipe it into `sed`

Comment: didn't work pipe with sed

Comment: scan_utc_time="14:21:49"
echo $scan_utc_time | sed -s 's/://g'

Comment: No the above solution didn't worked

Comment: It does work @BalaKrishna; `echo '14:21:49' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`

Comment: still it didn't work

scan_utc_time=$(scan_utc_time | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
bash: scan_utc_time: command not found

Comment: @0stone0 can u help me out

Comment: We'll need more details, `scan_utc_time: command not found` is caused because `scan_utc_time` isnt defined. Please [edit] your question to give us **all** the details about how you receive the timestamp.

Comment: You have `scan_utc_time=$(scan_utc_time | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')`. That likely needs to be `scan_utc_time=$(echo "$scan_utc_time" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')`

Answer (score 1):

With `tr`:

```
echo "14:21:49" | tr -d ':'
142149
```

`sed`:

```
echo "14:21:49" | sed -e 's/://g'
142149
```

`perl`:

```
echo "14:21:49" | perl -lpe 's/://g'
142149
```

---

In comments you have `scan_utc_time=$(scan_utc_time | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')` as *what does not work.*

That likely needs to be `scan_utc_time=$(echo "$scan_utc_time" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')`

ie, you are missing the sigil of `$` to dereference the value. As habit, that should be quoted as well.

Comment: consider time stamp is dynamic

Comment: Please say more? How are you getting the time stamp? Just take that and manipulate.

Comment: Time stamp will get from code

Answer (score 1):

Plain shell [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```sh
scan_utc_output_time=${scan_utc_input_time//:/}
```

Comment: In pipeline it was throwing an error called bad substitution

Comment: What pipeline? Please show.

Comment: aws pipeline bad substitution

Comment: You're not making it easy to help you. Show the code.